# How to padding two strings in printf?

Tags: c

For example:

```
printf("%-10s%s\n", s1, s2);
```

I can get:

```
s1         s2
```

I want to have s3 at a fixed column when the earlier strings might have varying lengths

```
printf("%s%s%s\n", s1, s2, s3); // how to padding 10?

s1s2         s3
s11s22       s3
s111s222     s3
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason you cannot concatenate `s1` and `s2` and pass them to `printf` together?

Comment: `printf("[%-10s]%s\n", s1, s2);` prints `[s1        ]s2` (but with 8 spaces, which SO decided to delete)

Comment: @kopecs why waste time and space to concatenate the string when you can just print them directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use a little bit of logic to work out how many spaces to print, e.g.:

```
int s3_column = 15;   // example position
int length = printf("[%s%s]", s1, s2);
if ( length >= 0 && length < s3_column )
    printf("%*s", (int)(s3_column - length), "");
printf("%s\n", s3);
```

As suggested in comments, another possible approach would be to prepare the `[s1s2]` part in its own buffer,  but that requires extra memory and incurs all the potential problems associated with memory allocation,  and will end up being more complicated code than calculating the spaces as in my example.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the point of the `(int)` cast in line 4?

Comment: @rici the argument for `*` must have type `int`.  In this code it's unnecessary but in general people might use `size_t` expressions for this sort of calculation so I have the habit of always including it

Answer (score 0):

```
void print_with_indent(int indent, char * string) { printf("%*s%s", indent, "", string); }
```

Comment: what is the value of indent?

Comment: How much you wish to have padding between the strings

Comment: I think they want to have `s3` at a fixed column when the earlier strings might have varying lengths

Answer (score 0):

with each `%s` include a n.m modifier (%n.ms) to place each string at a known starting point (and avoids overruns into the next strings desired location)  then make sure the sum of the 'm's places the third string exactly where you want it to begin.

--OR--

use an ANSI escape sequence after the second 'output format conversion' specifier to place the cursor where the third string is to begin

--OR--

run ncurses window and use `movexy()` to place the cursor where you want the third string to begin

--OR--

if using the `conio.h` library from Borland, then use:

```
gotoxy()`
```

--OR--

in windows

```
#include <windows.h>

void SetPosition(int X, int Y)
{
    HANDLE Screen;
    Screen = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD Position={X, Y};

    SetConsoleCursorPosition(Screen, Position);
}
```